# Rewrite HTTPS to HTTP with active certificate not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have HTTPS certificate installed for domain when i type http://domain.com it works when i type https://domain.com it does not redirect to http.
My .htaccess has

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think you need to change `off` to `on`

Answer (score 0):

> when i type https://domain.com it does not redirect to http.

Your `RewriteCond` directive limits the rule to domains starting with `www` so it will not match your test url of `domain.com`.

You can either test with `https://www.domain.com` or change the rule as below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#make the www optional
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I don't like this solution because I cannot understand what your intention is behind each of the rules e.g. the second rule you have should cause an infinite redirect (assuming these are the only rules in your .htaccess).

If you explain what your intention is for each rule, I would be able to provide a better answer

Comment: @JohnA LEt me know the URLs you tested with and the result that led you to conclude that it does not work.